# Skype bot participants

Tags: c#, botframework

I have build a skype bot with the Bot Connector from the Bot framework. I have added the skype bot to a group of users and are requesting the participants.

I was expecting that Participants would have all participants from the skype group, but it looks like it only contains the participant who speaks and the bot. Is there a way to get all the other participants in the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype currently doesn't support enumerating group membership so the best we can do right now is to include the speaker and the bot.  We are working with Skype to enable this scenario in the future.

Comment: Aren't there any skype api's i could use to fetch all the participants?

Answer (score 2):

Currently skype only models 1-1 interaction.